# Find exact point where 'make' fails

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm working with a modified version of Contiki in conjunction with an extension (a pub/sub system) and had to port some code around. This is on Linux.

Currently, the traditional 'make' execution of the pub/sub system fails, most likely because of a different folder structure.
I'm unable to find where I need to adjust it however and the problem is there are so many nested makefiles and include commands and such that I can't seem to find it. I get the error beneath and I know that the correct uip6.c location is /net/ip/uip6.c but I can't find the place to make that adjustment. Any suggestions on how I can identify that?

```
    selected command: make
execute make command with args:
make -f ../core/Makefile.looci loociCore.hex > debug.txt
/home/looci/looci/lnk/lc_contiki/platform/avr-zigduino/Makefile.early.avr-zigduino:1: loading AVR zigduino early makefile fuses
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/looci/looci/lnk/lc_contiki_os/.git'
/home/looci/looci/lnk/lc_contiki/core/reconfiguration/reconfigurationEngine.c: In function ‘on_event’:
/home/looci/looci/lnk/lc_contiki/core/reconfiguration/reconfigurationEngine.c:663:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mmem_freememory’
avr-gcc: /home/looci/looci/lnk/lc_contiki_os/core/net/uip6.c: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [obj_avr-zigduino/uip6.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Does make -n help? It shows what still needs to be done, so you might identify where make stopped.

Comment: If you have a new-enough version of GNU make you can add the `--trace` flag to get details about which recipes are invoked, why they're invoked, and where they appear in the makefiles.  If not you can use the `-d` flag, but that generates a LOT of output.

Comment: Use "set -v" on different places (nesting and includes, can be some work)